# Android Studio deleting recently added files

Tags: android-studio

The strangest thing/worst bug I ever saw:

I was in the Android Monitor screen and filtering log messages, when I pressed cmd+Z to undo the filtered text I wrote, I noticed the text didn't change but the mouse changed to "loading" for a split second, 
all to discover after a while that some recently added files were un-added (deleted) when I did the undo operation. 
I tried it again while carefully checking that the field was indeed taking the focus. same thing happened.

Any one having this issue?

Comment: sorry for your code

Comment: this happened when you pressed `cmd+z` after typing some code ?

Comment: no only when filtering through the logs. it happens quite often.